# Is there any way to open different tabs in hololens 2 app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I used `Application.OpenURL("www.google.uk")` to open a Website. This works but If I try to open more URL's only one will stay open.

I need a way to open more tabs.

This is my foreach where I need to open different tabs with ids provided above.

```
foreach ( var ids in mehrerenids)
        {   
         Application.OpenURL($"LINK/{ids}");
        }
```

Unity 2019.4.25f1
HoloLens 2

greetings

Comment: This is platform dependent. In the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html) they say 2019.4.25f1 should open multiple tabs each time it is called, for WebGL application, but apparently it does not work on your side, so should not be WebGL... Not sure if it works for Hololens, but could you try: `Application.ExternalEval("window.open('www.google.uk');");` ?

Comment: The edge browser you launched from Unity should be able to open multiple tabs at the same time. Could you provide more information about the "tabs" you mentioned and the     System Version number of your HoloLens?

Comment: @Pac0 Thanks for your answer, I tried it but nothing happends. 
Maybe it's not supported.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT The "tabs" I mentioned are just simply normal tabs that you open in your edge browser. Nothing special but it is not working right now. 

System Version number: 10.0.19041.1161

Comment: yeah, I don't think it's supported (yet?). Maybe contact support or unity forums ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching multiple tabs by looping code at the same time is not supported right now, it always launches only one Edge window, and only one tab shows in it.

Even though, `UnityEngine.WSA.Launcher.LaunchUri(uri, false)` can open the weblink and avoid the system suspend your app is by launching a flat browser window directly inside your unity app. But it still always holds only one slate at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe you could implement that in the future?

Comment: You can submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices. If it's a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule. For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).